# GWT or GXT for new Web Application

Tags: gxt

We are a small software Development company (<10) mainly in custom made Desktop Database applications. We have developed few Web Applications mainly used in VPN for centralized Query and reports with Flex 4.6, Spring, myBatis, Jasper Reports and Firebird. None of these is hosted on Publicly accessed web server but on VPN accessible cluster of 2/3 Load balanced Linux Tomcat servers.

Flex has been donated to Apache and Future development is geared towards (flaconJS) cross compilation to Java script, then a thought came forward "why not consider matured JS spitting Framework like GWT ?". We studied about GWT, GXT, smartGWT, vaadin, ZK. After reading many xxx vs yyy posts we have shortlisted GWT and GXT for our future data intensive web applications which may be hosted on Real world web servers. Considering our prospective client base we are considering to have GWT/similar for front end using REST calls to backend in either PHP or Spring/java depending on nature of project. We are also expecting requirements of Android Mobile applications augmenting already deployed projects.

Many of the POSTs which we have studied are from 2007 - 2012. Since then many things have changed so We feel that fresh opinions be sought before finalizing the decision. Our capabilities are, Java for 8 to 10 years, PHP never, HTML/CSS/JS never, Flex/spring/mybatis 8 to 10 years, RPC most of the time and REST for a recent project, Database applications in delphi > 15 yrs.

Clients Like Desktop Feel, very much fond of grids, modal popup data entry forms, tabbed views, menu navigation, expects use of ENTER even in Browser based forms, likes to preview reports before print/export etc. etc. We have shortlisted GWT/GXT based on these requirements, GXT demo application ticks most of the boxes. BTW we can afford to spend ample time for learning since we are planning for future development projects.

Please help us by sharing experience, suggestions, alternatives etc. etc. Your comments on this subject are valuable to us. We open to any other viable alternative so feel free to suggest it.

Thanks and warm regards.

Raja Patil

Comment: GXT is very good for developing Web or Desktop application. Its easier to use that pure GWT also, you can use all the components of GWT as it is with GXT. So, GXT with GWT is better option.
If you can go for JavaScript based frameworks, then you will have better design and response time. Sencha `ExtJs` is very rich with UI components. Its easy to learn and the has an excellent documentation and very active forum also. If your application is more data-driven, you can go for `AngularJS` but its learning curve is more steep

Comment: Thanks Vivek, Anyways we are thinking of changing development platform. We are looking for good client side platform but unable to decide due to lack of experience. Can u give us your choice between GWT/GXT and extJS/Angular i.e. between Java complied to JS or pure JS with framework. Our reading about JS coding is mainly horror stories so we tilted towards GWT/GXT. In short we are considering Client dev. platform which can talk to REST services in backend which can be either JAVA or PHP based. This way we may have to study 2 (GWT/GXT java-PHP) or 3 (JS-java-PHP) languages.

Comment: Pure JS based frameworks will give you more flexibilty. You will have more control over DOM, manipulation is easy. But, GWT/GXT makes your development very easy. It will depend on your requirement. And all of these can interact with JAVA based REST services. I myself worked with ExtJS, GWT and GXT. But, you can integrate AngularJS also with Java based REST services. See http://draptik.github.io/blog/2013/07/13/angularjs-example-using-a-java-restful-web-service/

Comment: Thanks for elaboration, I read about angularJS and watched a Introductory Video also got bit nervous since I could not make out anything from it since lack of knowledge about html/JS. Since we are conversant with JAVA we are tilting towards GWT, GXT. **Can you please suggest us what should we prefer between GWT and GXT ?** At present we feel that html/js just be differed for some time and meanwhile keep eye on how those frameworks evolve.

Comment: You can go for a combination of GWT and GXT. GXT is a wrapper over GXT and you can use GXT widgets along with GWT in one project. GXT widgets are compatible with GXT widgets and GWT widgets form the base for GXT

Comment: Thanks a lot Vivek, All team members agreed upon following plan. Start with plain gwt and have a test application One Crud Form with Grid, fetching data with REST (Jason), a simple Report with Jasper Report along with HTML Viewer, Use UI binder for creating data entry form. Enhance same with using GXT to compare. After this Final decision to be taken. BTW everybody accepted that HTML/CSS/JS should be given consideration and soon we will be arranging for basic training on these.

Comment: Why you can't go with combination of GXT and GWT? In the same app,  whenever you wnat to use GWT widgets, use them and wheneve you want to use GXT widgets, use them. After GXT `3.0.1` both are compatible. You can experiment on one thing, which widget GXT or GWT is suitable for your UI in which particular scenario. For ex- I prefer to use GWT `DateCell` with GXT `DateField` instead of using GXT DateCell. Both can be used together, depending on your requirement, you can choose one

Comment: We read some where that derivatives of GWT may not function properly when GWT is updated to new version so it was advised that developers should stay with GWT. Our team also felt that we should do atleast one small exercise both in GWT and GXT to know how money spent on GXT is justified in terms of productivity and UI quality. Superficially by looking at GXT explorer demo it is much better than GWT. However for real life projects we may not need most of them. Flex has comparable components to GWT and we are happy with those. Hope you throw some light on this by sharing your experience.